# recorrer array que contiene un base 64 string en php

Tags: php, java, android

tengo un problema, deseo recorrer lo que es un json en php, pero dentro del json puede venir n imagenes en formato string en base64

el problema esta en que cuando recorro el json con un foreach me manda este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen se esta moviendo al path, pero se mueve dañada

codigo con el que convierto en caso de venir una imagen

```
foreach ($data as $key => $jsons) { 
        if (preg_match('/-firma/i', $key)) {
             $path = "../webservices/img_formu/$name_img.png";
             $url = "".$name_img.".png";
             $json = json_decode($jsons, true);
             file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($json));
             $data[$key] = $url;
         }
}
```

cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida
de antemano gracias

Comment: Recuerda compartir el código y los mensajes de error como texto, por favor. Las personas no te van a contestar con imágenes

Comment: listo @Alfabravo

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver todo el código, parece que estás asumiendo que $data es un array asociativo y $jsons es el valor de un $key que contiene un formato json, el cual contiene una imagen en base64.
Pero viendo el mensaje de error, parece que realmente $data es un texto plano y foreach no es capaz de recorrerlo porque no es un array. Dado que $data es aparentemente formato json, conviértelo a array así:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true); // necesitas el true en este caso porque es asociativo.
foreach ($data as $key => $jsons) {
    if (preg_match('/-firma/i', $key)) {
        $json = json_decode($jsons, true);
        echo "La imagen podría ser "+$json['loquesea'];
        //o bien, recorrer el json
        foreach ($json as $jkey => $jvalue) {
            echo "json key: "+ $key +", value: "+$jvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, verificando el codigo $data si es un array, hice lo que haz puesto como respuesta, el inconveniente esta en que yo accedo al string base64 pero al decodificar la imagen que esta en el json el archivo resultante(un .png) esta dañado, no se podria ser tal vez que el string base64 este corrupto?,adjunto el codigo con el que convierto la imagen

Comment: Al parser que hace el foreach no le interesa mucho que el base64 esté corrupto (a menos que tenga carácteres especiales que rompan el formato del JSON)

Comment: @Alfabravo el base64 generado por android java puede tener un caracter especial que pueda romper el json, es que no le encuentro el por que al crear la imagen desde el json, me aparece imagen corrupta

Comment: ¿Cómo conviertes la imagen? Ya que puedes usarla directamente en base64 dentro de un <img> usando <img src="data:image/png;base64,$base64">
Igualmente intenta usar alguna herramienta online que convierta base64 a imagen a ver si funciona, y si es así debe funcionar el código html que estés implementando

Comment: estoy utilizando base64_decode en php para convertir la imagen